# How can I migrate a JIRA issue to Team Foundation Work Item Tracking (TFS WIT)?

Tags: jira, tfs-migration

I am transferring a  jira issue to TFS WIT in my company. My team used TFS2012, they use JIRA. So I want to migrate the JIRA issues into  TFS2012 WIT.

I want to preserve all the basic fields, attachments and comment history & work logging.

Any suggestions regarding tools or processes for this? 
I looked into dumping the issues into an Excel spreadsheet, but that doesn't include attachments or comments.

Comment: Can you please share how you went about it in the end? I have to do the same task - migrate JIRA over to TFS2012 WIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nearly 3week i worked on this task

finaly i got it

For this task we simply add USETFS plugin in jira that carry everything i mean comment tfsid and attachment everything its come under USETFS plugin in jira.

Answer (score 0):

[Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Good luck, the migration isn't usually a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

using comment-plugins we can export comment on excel....

here we can find the comment plugins 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/How+to+add+comments+to+Excel+export

(we could map this to History field in TFS once we export it to Excel)